# ExRam Gremlinq not working with Cosmos DB

Tags: c#, database, azure, azure-cosmosdb, gremlin

NuGet packages: ExRam.Gremlinq.Core, ExRam.Gremlinq.Providers, ExRam.Gremlinq.Providers.CosmosDb

Code:

```
        var _g = g.UseCosmosDb("example.gremlin.cosmos.azure.com", "myDb", "myGraphName", "myPrimaryKey==");

        var result = await _g.V().FirstAsync();
```

The graph has been populated with two Vertices and one edge between them.

Expected: result equals the first vertex

Result: await _g.V().FirstAsync() throws an exception with message

> System.MissingMethodException: 'Method not found: 'Void Gremlin.Net.Driver.GremlinClient..ctor(Gremlin.Net.Driver.GremlinServer, Gremlin.Net.Structure.IO.GraphSON.GraphSONReader, Gremlin.Net.Structure.IO.GraphSON.GraphSONWriter, System.String, Gremlin.Net.Driver.ConnectionPoolSettings, System.Action`1<System.Net.WebSockets.ClientWebSocketOptions>)'.'

Any ideas?

Comment: Seems that there is some package versioning issue, TBH.

Comment: @GuruStron You're right, I removed the reference to Gremlin.Net and now it works!

Comment: Glad to help you figure that out!

Comment: @user3713080 Thanks for Guru Stron's comment and you figured it out now. I just help you post it as answer and others can reference from you. You can accept(mark) it as answer. This can be beneficial to other community members. If you want share us with more details, you also could post more things as answer.  Thank you!

Comment: Exploring ExRam.Gremlinq, a .NET object-graph-mapper for Apache TinkerPop - Episode 9 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W32CZyfWWjY

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for @Guru Stron's comment and you figured it out now:

"I removed the reference to Gremlin.Net and now it works!"

I help you post it as answer and this can be beneficial to other community members.